# How to paste0 in plot in r?

Tags: r

With simple data:

```
set.seed(2015-04-13)
d = data.frame(x =seq(1,10),
           n1 = c(0,0,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6),
           logp = signif(-log10(runif(10)), 2))>
```

I can plot

```
 with(d, I plot(x, n1))
```

Now for my real data I need to do a for loop using i

```
 noquote(paste0("n",i))
[1] n1
```

I tried

```
i=1
with(d, plot(x, noquote(paste0("n",i))))
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
```

'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `get` to return the values from the environment of 'd'

```
with(d, plot(x, get(paste0("n",i)), ylab = paste0('n', i)))
```

Or extract the column from `d`

```
with(d, plot(x, d[[paste0("n", i)]], ylab = paste0('n', i)))
```

Or convert to `symbol` and `eval`uate

```
with(d, plot(x, eval(as.symbol(paste0('n', i))), ylab = paste0('n', i)))
```

Note: Both the above notations needs to change the axis labels for 'y'

---

Or another option is to create a formula with `paste`

```
plot(as.formula(paste0('n', i, '~ x')), data = d)
```